# Keep color from clicking on button after page redirects

Tags: javascript, jquery

When I click on a button, the color of the button changes correctly. However, when you click on a button, it redirects to an app route. How can I make the color from clicking on the button still remain after the page loads?

base.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <head>
        {% block head %}
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"
              integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T"
              crossorigin="anonymous">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="{{ url_for('static', filename='js/button_click.js') }}" type="text/javascript"
                charset="UTF-8"></script>

        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='css/dashboard.css') }}">

        <title>{% block title %}{% endblock %}</title>
        {% endblock %}
    </head>
    <body>
    {% block content %}
    <div class="navbar">
        <div class="logo-holder">
            <img class="logo" src="{{ url_for('static', filename='img/logo.png') }}" alt="Logo">
        </div>
        <div class="button-holder">
            <button class="navbtn" id="orange-btn" onclick="window.location = '/orange';">Orange</button>
        </div>
        <div class="button-holder">
            <button class="navbtn" id="banana-btn" onclick="window.location = '/banana';">Banana</button>
        </div>
        <div class="button-holder">
            <button class="navbtn" id="apple-btn" onclick="window.location = '/apple';">Apple</button>
        </div>

    </div>
    {% endblock %}
    </body>
    </html>
```

button_click.js:

```
$('.button-holder').click( function () {
    $(this).toggleClass('active_button');
});
```

dashboard.css:

```
.button-holder:active, .active_button {
      background-color: #992200;
}
```

Comment: as an advice: use <a> tag instead of <button> and style it like a button. but it's not related to your question though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're on a new page, you need to identify which page you're on and activate the appropriate button.

```
    window.onOpen = function () {
        const thisURL = window.location;
        if (thisURL.includes('/orange') {
            document.getElementById('orange-btn').classList.add('active-class');
        }
        /* and so forth for the other buttons */
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add a value to the localStorage and then on new page check it and assign to the button again. Also please note that localstorage saved your clicked button value only for your device, not globally.
Besides, please change  to anchor tag  if you want to use links.
Try like this:

HTML:

```
<div class="button-holder">
            <a href="/orange" class="navbtn" id="orange-btn">Orange</a>
        </div>
        <div class="button-holder">
            <a href="/banana" class="navbtn" id="banana-btn">Banana</a>
        </div>
        <div class="button-holder">
            <a href="/apple" class="navbtn" id="apple-btn" >Apple</a>
        </div>
```

JS:

```
$(function(){

    var button_index = localStorage.getItem('button_index');
    if(button_index ){
        $('.button-holder').eq(button_index).addClass('active_button');
    }


    $('.button-holder').click( function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        var url = window.location   + $(this).find("a").attr('href');
        var button_index = $(this).index();
        $(this).toggleClass('active_button');
        localStorage.setItem('button_index', button_index - 1 );
        window.location = url;
    });



})
```

Comment: Good answer. However, if you do it this way when it redirects to the next page, it makes all the buttons colored.

Comment: @dfahsjdahfsudaf you can give a special ID to the button that you want to be colored.

Comment: What do you mean by that?

Comment: @dfahsjdahfsudaf You want only the exact button that was clicked be colored with class "button-holder" to be colored right?

Comment: Yes that's correct. Sorry was asking how would I implement the special ID to the button in the code?

Comment: @dfahsjdahfsudaf in this case even ID is not requred, I updated my answer code, please try it.

Comment: Tried it. Weird. When you click "Orange".. it redirects to '/orange' but the "Banana" button is now colored. Seems like the button next to the one you want gets colored instead.